# Spring webclient oauth set principal name

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I have a custom WebClient bean that's set up to make OAuth requests to fetch a token before making requests to a protected resource. The WebClient bean looks like this

```
    @Bean
    fun webClient(reactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager: ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager): WebClient? {
        val oauth2ClientCredentialsFilter =
            ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(reactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager)
        oauth2ClientCredentialsFilter.setDefaultClientRegistrationId(<registration_name>)

        return WebClient.builder()
            .filter(oauth2ClientCredentialsFilter)
            .build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun reactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
        clientRegistrations: ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository?,
        authorizedClients: ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService?,
    ): ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager? {
        val authorizedClientManager =
            AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrations, authorizedClients)
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(
            ClientCredentialsReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider(),
        )
        return authorizedClientManager
    }
```

However, when I try to make requests with this webclient and initiate the client credentials oauth flow, I get a
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: principalName cannot be empty`
when using the resulting token. My initial reaction is to try and set the principal name on all authorization requests made with this WebClient. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my question was misinformed. The issue wasn't with not setting the principal name on the WebClient OAuth config. The issue actually was with the incoming JWTs into our system missing a `sub` claim. I just had to alter our JWT Decoder to handle the case where the `sub` claim was null and set a default value.